# How do I get one main function that prompts the user for a string to run other functions that manipulates the string?

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I am trying to create a program to play around with some of the string manipulation abilities of python. I have made functions that successfully manipulate the strings. What I am having difficulty with is figuring out how to to create a main function that runs all of the other functions in order. Here is the code that I have so far

```
def main():
    print("This program demonstrates Python's String manipulation ability")
    s=input("Enter a String: ")
def change(s):
    firstchar=s[0]
    modifieds=s[1:].replace(firstchar.lower(),"$")
    modifieds=modifieds.replace(firstchar.upper(),"$")
    final=(firstchar+modifieds)
    print(final)
def reverse(s):
res=""
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i%2==0:
        res+=(s[i].lower())
    else:
        res+=(s[i].upper())
return res[::-1]
def code(s):
    string=s.upper()
    n=len(string.split(" "))
    print()
    output=""
    for i in string:
        output+=chr(ord(i)+n)
    print(output)
main()
```

Comment: You're gonna have to explain this more clearly. What's the sequence of functions you want to runt? What do you want to do with the output of these manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
def main():
    print("This program demonstrates Python's String manipulation ability")
    return input("Enter a String: ")

def change(s):
    firstchar=s[0]
    modifieds=s[1:].replace(firstchar.lower(),"$")
    modifieds=modifieds.replace(firstchar.upper(),"$")
    final=(firstchar+modifieds)
    print(final)

def rev(s):
    res=""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i%2==0:
            res+=(s[i].lower())
        else:
            res+=(s[i].upper())
    return res[::-1]

def code(s):
    string=s.upper()
    n=len(string.split(" "))
    print()
    output=""
    for i in string:
        output+=chr(ord(i)+n)
    print(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = main()
    print(change(user_input))
    print(rev(user_input))
    code(user_input)
```

Doesn't hurt to pycodestyle/pep8 your code. I renamed the reverse function so not to get it confused with the built-in reverse() method.

I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but here is what it outputs:

```
james@zingbot:~/Desktop$ ./test.py 
This program demonstrates Python's String manipulation ability
Enter a String: asdf
asdf
None
FdSa

BTEG
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. I am not sure where the output "none" is coming from. Do you have any idea on how to remove it from the output?

Answer (score 0):

your reverse(s) functions indentations are not valid, if I am not wrong....